# Are there browser-based IDEs or other apps that'll let me program on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have a lot of time with only an iPhone to entertain me. Is there a way to writte programs on this thing? Any language, as long as the programs will run either directly in the browser or in an app.

Note: I said on the iPhone, not for the iPhone.

Comment: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mides-ide/id284965983?mt=8 or  http://webdesktoplife.com/post/1358032790/a-javascript-ide-for-the-iphone ? I have not used them but it's what a Google search turned up. Worth a look?

Comment: As far as I know you could try using one of those Browser IDE's . Other than that I have not seen any. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200949/browser-based-ides

Comment: no there is not, and there are not really thousands of apps in the app store, its all just an illusion..... so yeah the iphone doesnt really run programms, sorry about that

Comment: @cwoebker: don't worry - the habit of reading the question before answering it is an acquired skill. You can still get it.

Comment: oh yeah, my fault i am sorry... i guess you could always write small python scripts and execute them with mobile terminal^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my guess you want to do programming on your iPhone.  You can easily do this by remote desktop'ing into a computer at home (or anywhere) with your iPhone.

You can use [Logmein](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/logmein-ignition/id299616801?mt=8) for this.  Though I will tell you, it's a little tricky with the on screen keyboard.  Then you can pick any language, or any development tools your computer has.

This would be how I would do it (though I'd try to purchase a physical keyboard)

Comment: That'd be a programmers nightmare

Comment: I can hardly stand entering 32 characters of WiFi key using the screen keyboard. Thinking about entering regexes this way makes me fell sorry for anyone who ever attemtps that.

Comment: heh, it's not pretty, but any kind of programming you will be doing on a phone will be tricky, as programming = typing (most of the time). 3rd party keyboard for the win, still isn't as good as a PC

Comment: @Spooks yep that would probably be the way I would do it, it's never going to be pretty on a phone, but if Emaille really wants to do it, that would be the best way.